# Can Sharepoint support 46000 user and how much does it cost?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, licensing

So we plan to deploy Microsoft Sharepoint on a private cloud for a large country wide institution.
Our installation has to support approximatively 46000 user.

I would like to know if sharepoint have been used in such scale and if so did it work well?
 
I would like to know also how much it is going to cost in licensing fees?

Comment: You might consider checking out the Software Boundaries and Limits page - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx - but it can definitely scale up way more than 46k users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on many reasons. For example, technically is possible because you can create more databases for My Site contents. Each Content Database has a limit for mysite Site Collections (7500 SC). for 46000 users you will need 7 Content DBs.

There aren't any phisical barrier. Just take into account that the more servers you need the more money you have to spend and more management resources.

Regarding the licensing fees, depends on what you negotiate with Microsoft, the version of SharePoint (Foundation

> Licensing_Microsoft_SharePoint_Server_2013.pdf

to have an idea of what you need. Keep in mind that the single standard license per server is about $7000.